# wget not downloading entire file

Tags: wget

I got historic house prices in UK from: https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/price-paid-data-downloads

I ran the link for all historic house prices:

```
wget http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-complete.csv -P /dbfs/FileStore/tables
```

to download the file.

I tried multiple times, and get a small file, 7MB:

[image]

The webpage says it is 4GB:

[image]

Any suggestions what I can be doing wrong?

Comment: I have tried the same command and have got 473MiB of the file so far. Please check your network connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should that:

```
wget -P <path> <URL>
```

Your case:

```
wget -P /dbfs/FileStore/tables http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-complete.csv
```

More detail: [wget](https://www.linuxnix.com/linux-wget-download-to-a-directory-or-folder/)

---

Update:

```
wget -P /dbfs/FileStore/tables  --no-check-certificate --no-proxy http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-complete.csv
```

Comment: Actually, same issue:`2019-09-25 09:29:57 (9.30 MB/s) - ‘/dbfs/FileStore/tables/pp-complete.csv.4’ saved [4301888603/4301888603]` was what wget returned, but when I ran the ls -l, `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6921307 Sep 25 09:30 pp-complete.csv.4`

Comment: Do you have enough free space in your directory? Try to continue downloading : wget -c http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-complete.csv in the same directory you were during the original download.

Comment: as downloading, I got this error: `*** WARNING: skipped 2928116 bytes of output ***
`. The number corresponds to the missing data. Very odd

Comment: @alex Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1176513/edit) to reflect all the details you posted in comments. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage. See also [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/217657)

Comment: I downloaded this file in `Chrome browser` and get complete file: `-rw-r--r-- 1 biennt biennt 4301888603 Thg 9 26 16:46 pp-complete.csv` . So weird!Try clone this repo: [URL](https://github.com/circulosmeos/gdown.pl) and run:  `./gdown.pl https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zmp3tf3g1kaMpG949iIFQjZqvLOFJlrr/edit pp-complete.csv`

Comment: It turned out the system I was using had that webpage access black listed. discussed with security and gained access.